# Array how to combine a variable and text

Tags: php

Below is code:

```
$domainname     = $_POST[domainname];
        array(
                'action' => 'create',
                'domain' => '.website.com',
                'create' => 'Create'
    ));
```

I need to add variable `$domainname` to `'domain'`.

I try to do somelike this but not working:

```
    array(
            'action' => 'create',
            'domain' => .$domainname'.website.com',
            'create' => 'Create'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

**change:**

```
'domain' => .$domainname'.website.com',
```

**To:**

```
'domain' => $domainname.'.website.com',
```